# How to read value in the createState method of StatefulWidget

Tags: android, ios, flutter, sharedpreferences

Hello I want to read the value from the SharedPreferences inside the `createState` of the `StatefulWidget`.

I tried to add `async` after the method but it doesn't work. What is the correct way to do ?

```
class LoginScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LoginScreenState createState() {

    // check if user is logged. If logged then send user to dashboard else keep it here


    return new _LoginScreenState();
  }
}
```

Comment: That's not a good idea. Do it in `initState()` of `_LoginScreenState()` instead.

Comment: How to do there ?

Comment: Nothing special, just do it and use `setState(() { ...})` to update the value when it's available. This is a FAQ and there should be several answers for that on StackOverflow already.

Comment: I'd use `didChangeDependencies` instead in case the user disconnect. User details most likely comes from an InheritedWidget anyway

Answer (score 3):

You don't.

You should not have anything inside `createState` beside the state creation. If you want to do these kind of check, do them inside the `State` class instead:

```
class MyState extends State<MyWidget> {
  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    // check if the user is logged
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use createState to read the values, you can use `initState` or `FutureBuilder` maybe.

```
class LoginScreen extends StatefulWidget {
    @override
    _LoginScreenState createState() => _LoginScreenState();
  }

  class _LoginScreenState extends State<LoginScreen> {
    String value;

    _readPreference() async {
      SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      //refresh your screen based on the current parameter
      setState(() {
        value = prefs.getString("your_value_key");
      });
    }

    @override
    void initState() {
      _readPreference();
      super.initState();
    }

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Container();
    }
  }
```